# HTML JQuery - Input Mask Decimal with Leading Zeros

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this textbox where in the user will input a coordinate and can also convert it to Decimal format. The problem is this if the user manually inputs the coordinate, it's working fine but if they copied a coordinate especially with the second format, it doesn't display the way I want to.

For example this coordinate: `120° 58' 9.1524` if I paste that into the textbox, it became `120° 58' 120° 58' 91.524000"` instead of `120° 58' 09.152400`.

How can I add a zero on the "second" in DMS if the value is 10 below? I tried using the inputmask   but it puts the 0 at the end.

**HTML**
`<input type="text" placeholder="Coordinate X Longitude" id="coord_x" class="form-control">`

**Jquery**

```
$("#coord_x").inputmask({
  "mask"  : "999° 99' 99.999999\" E",
  "placeholder":"0"
});
```

**External Scripts**
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced your static mask with a dynamic mask like this:

```
9{1,3}° 9{1,2}' 9{1,2}.9{1,6}
```

Here's a link at the readme page where the author explains the difference between a static mask and a dynamic mask:

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#via-jquery-plugin

> - $(selector).inputmask("99-9999999");  //static mask
> - $(selector).inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999-9999"}); //specifying    options
> - $(selector).inputmask("9-a{1,3}9{1,3}"); //mask with dynamic syntax

```js
$("#coord_x").inputmask({    
  "mask"  : "9{1,3}° 9{1,2}' 9{1,2}.9{1,6}",
  "placeholder": "0"
});
```

```css
#coord_x{
  display: block;
}

blockquote{
  background: lightgray;
  border: dashed 2px gray;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: monospace, courier;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/5.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>


<input type="text" placeholder="Coordinate X Longitude" id="coord_x" class="form-control">  
<blockquote>120° 58' 9.1524</blockquote>
```

Comment: of course if you had the chance to see the solution it would be nice to hear any comment to be sure you have clear what's going on there. Your mask was static and that means that the input expected EXACTLY those number of characters specified in the mask even if the number in your case was smaller. Or maybe did you actually mean to transform the input in a way that it fulfilled the static mask adding zeros on the least significant digit positions?

Comment: this really works thank you so much! I've been struggling this since yesterday!
The reason I want to transform it with adding zeros on the "second" is because it always moves/adds the first decimal to the whole number which will lead to wrong conversion/coordinates.

Comment: Sorry too I got somehow confused on the dynamic part. I just got focused on doing a regex patter which I think it's a way and somehow didn't notice the dynamic mask.

Comment: the answer posted by @zer00ne addressed the problem in a more specific way without involving the jQuery inputmask plugin. Maybe you want to consider his solution also... of course feel free to switch correct answer if you prefer the other one

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it without a plugin.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
/*
For demonstration purposes
Click to copy to clipboard
*/
$('.copy').on('click', function(e) {
  this.select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.value);
});
/*
Changes to value will happen after user unfocuses
*/
$('.coord').on('change', format);

function format(e) {
  /*
  If value length is greater than 0...
  ...split() value at each space and '.'...
  ...If the first number doesn't end with '°'...
  ...add it
  ...If the second number doesn't end with "'"...
  ...add it
  ...Zero pad the start of third number and...
  ...add it to the fourth number and zero pad...
  ...the end of it -- save it as "long"...
  ...remove the fourth number from array...
  ...assign the third number of array as "long"...
  ...join() the array and assign it to <input>
  */
  if (this.value.length > 0) {
    let parts = this.value;
    parts = parts.split(/[\s.]/);
    console.log(parts);
    if (!parts[0].endsWith('°')) {
      parts[0] = parts[0] + '°';
    }
    if (!parts[1].endsWith("'")) {
      parts[1] = parts[1] + "'";
    }
    let long = parts[2].padStart(2, '0') + '.' + parts[3].padEnd(6, '0');
    parts.pop();
    parts[2] = long;
    parts.length = 4;
    this.value = parts.join(' ');
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control coord" type="text" placeholder="Coordinate X Longitude">
<input class="form-control coord" type="text" placeholder="Coordinate Y Longitude"><br>
<!-- For demonstration purposes -->
<label>Click to Copy: 
  <input class='copy' value="120° 58' 9.1524">
</label>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```